# How to connect excel file to my django website project?

Tags: python, django, web, file-upload

I spent 2 night to solve this ploblem...

My first question in stackoverflow

In views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
  
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../../analysis')
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render(
    request, 'blog/upload.html', {'form': form}
)
```

In models.py

```
class UploadFileModel(models.Model):
title = models.TextField(default='')
file = models.FileField(null=True)
```

I implemented excel,csv file's uploading in my website.

And file is saved in '_media' folder.

I want to execute machine running code with this excel file.

How can i get name of uploaded file?

Plz...